# Does Xcode 11.2 scene editor allow adding components?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

Using Xcode 11.2 I can create a new project using the "Game" template.  I can include for "Game Technology" SpriteKit and check "Integrate GameplayKit".  If I run the code at this point on an iPhone 11 Pro iOS 13.2 simulator I see the "Hello, World!" label.  If I go into the Library and add a Color Sprite at position (0,0) to the GameScene.sks file when I run I see the red Color Sprite.  My problem comes when I add a Swift file with the content

```
import GameplayKit

class MovementComponent : GKComponent {

    override func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {
        print(seconds)
    }
}
```

and use the components editor in Xcode to add this component to the Color Sprite.  When I run this I get a grey screen.  When I check the GameViewController file I see with the debugger that scene.rootNode is nil.  What's going wrong?  I just want to see how to integrate a component with a Color Sprite using the components editor.  Does this stuff work at all or is this just for WWDC demos?

Comment: Are you retaining the entity?  You need to properly call the GKScene to generate the components, then retain them.

Comment: I added a Color Sprite using the scene editor and a component I wrote (shown above) to that Color Sprite.  That's it.  No other code.  Straight from Apple's template.  Where am I suppose to add code to retain the entity when Apple's code doesn't even retain the scene.rootNode?

Comment: I have yet to use 11.2,  but when you create your GKScene, you need to extract out the entities and save it in a spot you need to access entities (Or save your GKScene). This is usually the Scene.  If your Scene is not custom,  then stash it in the userData for that scene.

Comment: Apple's template has `if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? { sceneNode.entities = scene.entities; sceneNode.graphs = scene.graphs; ...}`.  If the scene.rootNode is nil that does little but it seems to be what you are suggesting if I understand what you wrote.  I am using nothing custom except the MovementComponent.swift file.  My question includes each step (except naming the project) that I used to determine this stuff isn't working.

Comment: scene.rootNode should not be nil.  If it is nil, then you do not have a valid GKScene, so your component system will fail.

Comment: add a generic component to your scene,  perhaps that is why the system is failing on you.

Comment: Agree.  It shouldn't be nil.  I use Apple's template, add a component, and the scene.rootNode that was not nil before I added the component is now nil.

Comment: MovementComponent seems to me as generic a component as you can get.

Comment: but add it to the scene, not the sprite

Comment: Just tried adding it to the scene and not the sprite.  Same issue.  scene.rootNode is nil.  Screen is grey.  Nothing else shows up.

Comment: I honestly do not know.  I would recommend building a new scene and just adding a component to it, no sprite, and see if you get the same results.  This does work because I use it, but like I said I am not on 11.2

Comment: Just tried creating a new project with Apple's Game template only adding the generic MovementComponent to the Scene object.  Same problem.  When I remove it I see the "Hello, World!" label that the template has.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201851/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-gerard).

Answer (score 3):

Appears to be a bug in Xcode 11.2.  Following the steps above the behavior appears correct for Xcode 10.3.  Filled out Apple Feedback FB7427190.  Thanks Knight0fDragon for helping identify where the problem was.

Comment: I received some feedback from Apple. They wanted me to try explicitly overriding the required initWithCoder and supportsSecureCoding methods for every class that uses GKComponent as a superclass. This seems to solve the problem for one my SKScenes but not both.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I just added the following to each of my components:
`override init() {
    super.init()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

override class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { true }
`

Comment: @DonovanVoss - holy crap - that worked! Just this line was needed `override class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { true }`. You should post this as an answer

Comment: Current status as of 3 July 2020 from Apple is "Software Engineering will need to fix this bug but hasn’t been able to yet."

Comment: Hm.  I have a project where adding those overrides worked for many of the .sks files with components, but not all of them. I added the override code to all the components in the project, but there are still some .sks files which fail to load (rootNode as nil), even though everything appears to load fine otherwise.

Comment: @cc that's the same thing I'm seeing.  Apple said my idea of just redoing this stuff in code instead of their editor is something I can do.

Comment: I discovered that if you have a .sks file that uses the "alpha outline" physics definition, the rootNode nil thing happens there, too.  Maybe that's your issue.

Comment: @cc I've tried removing various things in my .sks and sometimes something appears to work during an editing session but doesn't later when I try to isolate that one edit.  I've spent hours trying to isolate the problem.  At this point I can code it up faster than pursuing a fix for a bug that Apple won't probably resolve until iOS 14.  Their lack of progress does not instill confidence in the use of the scene editor.

Comment: I hear you. Problems with the scene editor have been pretty consistent, even before this particular issue.

Comment: I tried my app with the latest iOS 14 public beta (18A55351d).  Everything seems to be working.  I closed out the bug with Apple since I have no confidence they'll fix anything in iOS 13.6.1 (17G80) which still has the problem.  When I contacted Apple DTS they refused to look at the problem because there was a bug report on it.  I figure closing out the bug will force DTS to at least help people even if it's to admit there's no solution.  Better than being given the Apple run around.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my post today is a duplicate of this post.

[SKScene not loaded when add GKComponent to GameScene.sks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449011/skscene-not-loaded-when-add-gkcomponent-to-gamescene-sks?noredirect=1#comment106946044_60449011)

It seems that the problem still exist in Xcode 11.3.1

If there is no component added in the scene editor to a SKSpriteNode I see that the scene is completely loaded as GameScene.sceneDidLoad is called.

If there is a GKComponent added in the scene editor. The GameScene is not loaded - GameScene.sceneDidLoad is never called.