# SKScene not loaded when add GKComponent to GameScene.sks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I am currently creating a 2D game with Swift SpriteKit and GameplayKit.
I have a GameScene.sks file and a GameScene.swift file that is of type SKScene.
Now I wanted to add a Component of type GKComponent. I created my component and added it to one of my SKSpriteNodes in GameScene.sks
[image: New Created Component]

However after adding the Component to the SpriteNode in the Scene Editors Inspector the Scene is no longer loaded and the app shows only a grey screen.

[image]

Is this a known issue in XCode?
Is there a way of bypassing this issue?

I have not uploaded any example code. The issue is reproducable by any new XCode Project (ios / Game) that supports SpriteKit and GameplayKit. 
Just add a class that is derived from GKComponent and add the class to the given helloLabel in the Scene Editor.

This is how the GameScene is loaded:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? {
                // This gets only executed when I remove the Component from the SKSpriteNode in the Scene Editor.
            }
        }
        ...
```

Comment: Show your code that loads the scene

Comment: I test and works fine, can try cloning this https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/tree/master/ComponentTest ? For some reason your file it seems that it is not in the project.

Comment: Thanks @Maetschl, you are right. Your provided code works absolutely fine. I've also tried to add more new created components and even this worked fine.
Now I will try with a new created project.

Comment: @Maetschl: I've tried now on a different machine. Same result. I am not able to launch my app if the loaded GameScene has a SpriteNode where a GKComponent is added.

Even with a new created GameScene.sks file it is not possible.


I really wonder what you have done different to me?
Cheers

Comment: Now I've tried to add another GameScene to your project, changed to load the new GameScene via the GameViewController. Added a SKSpriteNode to the scene and added a component to the SpriteNode. -> Same result. Again a grey screen. Somehow it seems that the creation of sks files is corrupted. At least on my machines.

Comment: I recommend you update XCode to the latest version.

Comment: I am already using the latest version Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)